# Set responsive stack height with background image

Tags: flutter

I want to set height of stack - first item in it is container with background image. I don't want to write hardcoded value or to calculate it using list.length (because on some screens it looks good, on some doesn't).

Is it possible somehow to set the background image of my column using some other approach than this?

I don't want this extra space on the bottom (under trophy icon) - on my phone this looks good, but on emulator I get this:
[image]

```
Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: ride.stopPoints.length * 50 + 170, // this needs to change
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                image: AssetImage("lib/images/background.jpg"), // my image that stretches based on the number of stopPoints
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: screenWidth * 0.25,
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(...),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.public, color: Color(0xFFA41723)),
                      SizedBox(width: 5),
                      Text(
                        "Ruta:",
                        ...
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const Icon(Icons.emoji_flags, color: Color(0xFF3F3F3F)),
                        const SizedBox(width: 5),
                        Text(
                          ride.startingPoint,
                          ...
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: ride.stopPoints.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
                          const Row(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(...),
                                child: Text(
                                  " |",
                                  ...
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                const Icon(
                                  Icons.adjust,
                                  size: 16,
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                                Text(
                                  ride.stopPoints[index],
                                 ...
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ]);
                      },
                    ),
                    const Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(...),
                          child: Text(
                            " |",
                            ...
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const Icon(Icons.emoji_events_outlined, color: Color(0xFF3F3F3F)),
                        const SizedBox(width: 5),
                        Text(
                          ride.finishingPoint,
                          ...
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Try wrapping the `Stack` with `Card`, if it does't work you can try replacing the `Container` with `Card` too.

Comment: I still need to have height attribute on `Container` widget

Comment: Thats what i'm telling try replacing that container with `Card` and don't give hight, card has property it take hight of child. It should work for you